# Is there an analytic continuation of the Pell and its companion sequences to the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I'm finishing some work related to the Pell and its half-companion sequences ($P_{n}$ and $H_{n}$).  I found a video series (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLP8japRypwHmtdpyApWY_R6A_c0BKbT1W) which shows how the Fibonacci and Lucas sequences transform into continuous functions of a complex number, valid on the entire complex plane (I think).  I did a similar transformation for $P_{n}$ and $H_{n}$.

Q1: Are these correct?  $P\left(z\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(-i\right)^{z-1}\sin\left(-iz \log \left(i \delta_{S}\right)\right)$ and $H\left(z\right) = \left(-i\right)^{z}\cos\left(-iz \log \left(i \delta_{S}\right)\right)$, where $\delta_{S} = \sqrt{2}+1$?

A1: They are correct for integer $z$.  First, I cleaned up the argument:
$$-in \log \left(i \delta_{S}\right) = -iz\left(\log{e^{i\pi/2}}-i\log{\delta_{S}}\right) = \frac{\pi z}{2}-iz\log{\delta_{S}}$$

Then, I verified by subbing in for $z$: $z = n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and using $$ \sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}-iz\log{\delta_{S}}\right) = \frac{e^{in\pi/2} \cdot e^{n \log \delta_{S}} - e^{-in\pi/2} \cdot e^{-n \log \delta_{S}}}{2i} \text{ and }\\
\cos\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}-iz\log{\delta_{S}}\right) = \frac{e^{in\pi/2} \cdot e^{n \log \delta_{S}} + e^{-in\pi/2} \cdot e^{-n \log \delta_{S}}}{2}.$$ What I obtained were the Binet forms of $P_{n}$ and $H_{n}$. I still could use some help with Q2 and Q3.

Q2: Is there a better way to express these?

Q3:  If there exists some function of $P_{n}$ and $H_{n}$, when can I substitute in the complex versions?  Suppose I have $$\frac{P^{2}_{n}-1}{P^{2}_{n}}.$$  Can I just sub in?  I know there will be poles whenever the denominator is $0$ and zeros whenever the numerator is $0$.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether your $P$ and $H$ give the right answers for $z=1,2,\dotsc$?

Comment: I did in the past and everything checked out, using the exponetial form of sin(z) and cos(z).  I'll re-check tomorrow after I get some sleep.